# Clone a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, clone

Hello I have a class called Ladrillo and in another class I have a 2d array type Ladrillo.
I want to clone that array so that if the original one changes this one doesnt.

From what I read online in my ladrillo class I have to put Implements clonable.
I did that and the following code but it didn't work:

```
Ladrillo [][] copy=new Ladrillo[original.length][original.length];

for(int i=0;i<original.length;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<original.length;j++){
   Ladrillo newLadrillo=original[i][j].clone();
   copy[i][j]=newLadrillo;
 }}
```

Any ideas on what to change? I believe I have to add something on the class Ladrillo but I haven't figured it out.
Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean by _it didn't work:_? Please specify exact problem you are facing, What do you expect and what is currently happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a copy constructor? What language are you using?

See [What is a copy constructor in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168201/what-is-a-copy-constructor-in-c)

Comment: I am using java what is a copy constructor?

Answer (score 0):

The clone() method only creates a shallow copy of Arrays if its values are not primitives. For a deep copy you could use the static method

```
java.lang.System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

or implement the clone() method in your Ladrillo class. Here comes an example for a class called Player with two fields that should be copied when the clone() method is called. We're simply calling its superclass ( which is java.lang.Object for the Player class) clone() - method and cast the result to Player.

```
public class Player implements Cloneable {
   public String name;
   public int    age;

  @Override
  public Player clone() {
    try {
     return (Player) super.clone();
    }
    catch ( CloneNotSupportedException e ) { // its cloneable
     throw new InternalError();
    }
  }
}
```