# Pointer is initialized but I have error "Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC". Why?

Tags: c++, error-handling, initialization

My function `zeroPadding` has more options but I put only two because they're important for this example. When I debug the `main()` function I got this error

```
Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC
```

Why?

---

This is from the class `Signal` just to show what the constructor calls

```
template <class T> Signal<T>::Signal(int width,int height){
    N=width; 
    M=height;
    sig2D= new int*[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        sig2D[i]=new int[M];
    }
    t0=0;
    deltaT=1;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<M;j++){
        sig2D[i][j]=t0+j*deltaT;
    }
}
```

---

```
    template <class T> Image<T>::Image(int width,int height): Signal(width,height) {}

    template <class T> Image<T> Image<T>::zeroPadding(Image<T> im2){

        Signal<T> s1= static_cast<Signal<T>>(*this);
        Signal<T> s2= static_cast<Signal<T>>(im2);   

        int *temp=new int[15];
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
        temp[i]=0;
    }

        if(s1.getWidth()>s2.getWidth() && s1.getHeight()==s2.getHeight()){

            im2.setWidth(s1.getWidth());
            im2.sig2D=new T*[im2.getWidth()];
            for(int i=0;i<im2.getWidth();i++){
                im2.sig2D[i]=new T[im2.getHeight()];
            }

            for (int i=s2.getWidth();i<s1.getWidth();i++)
                for(int j=0;j<s2.getHeight();j++){
                    im2.sig2D[i][j]=temp[j];
                }   
                return im2;

        }
          else if(s1.getHeight()<s2.getHeight() && s1.getWidth()>s2.getWidth()){
        setHeight(s2.getHeight());
        sig2D=new T*[getWidth()];
        for(int i=0;i<getWidth();i++){
            sig2D[i]=new T[getHeight()];
        }

        for (int i=0;i<s1.getWidth();i++)
            for(int j=s1.getHeight();j<s2.getHeight();j++){
                sig2D[i][j]=temp[j];
            }   
            (*this).zeroPadding(im2);
            }
    }    

    template <class T> Image<T> Image<T>::addImage(Image<T> im2){
        Image<T> *r=new Image(80,80);


        if ((*this).getWidth()==im2.getWidth() && (*this).getHeight()==im2.getHeight()) {
            //r=new Image(im2.getWidth(),im2.getHeight());
            for (int i=0;i<im2.getWidth();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<im2.getHeight();j++)
                (*r).sig2D[i][j]= (*this).sig2D[i][j]+im2.sig2D[i][j];
            }
            return(*r);
        }
        else {
          (*r)= zeroPadding(im2); // here breaks why?
              addImage(*r); 
        }

    int main() {

        Image<int> *a= new Image<int>(5,6);
        Image<int> *b= new Image<int>(4,7);

        (*a).addImage(*b);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In this case `Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC` means you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. Use a debugger! Also stop it with the `(*this).` and use `this->` instead.

Comment: try valgrind or similar

Comment: `int temp[]={0};` This array has only one element in it. You are then attempting to access `temp[j]` where `j` has values other than `0`.

Comment: If it says there's an access violation *reading* a location, the problem shouldn't be with what `r` points to, but something else.

Comment: C++ doesn't support implied int like in `N=width; M=height;`. And you should never use it like that

Comment: BTW, 0xCCCCCCCC is one of the magical numbers in VC that programmers should know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new it'll help debugging uninitialized memory much easier

Comment: But I still don't understand where I didn't initialize r or something else.

Comment: I when I called (*r)=(*r).zeroPadding(im2) instead of (*r)=zeroPadding(im2) it passed so it's not problem with r, problem is with (*this). I tought that (*this) is initialized in main(), am I wrong?

Comment: use a debugger and find out where the program stopped. And remember to check after allocation. You're creating an array `int *temp=new int[15];`, `sig2D= new int*[N];` and then use it without checking the `new` has completed successfully

Comment: I debug in main function in line (*a).addImage(*b) so debugger come to (*r)=zeroPadding(im2); and after that go through zeroPadding and come back to line (*r)=zeroPadding(im2); and I click Step over and breaks.

Comment: Does the class `Signal` have a [copy constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168201/what-is-a-copy-constructor-in-c) or a [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)? If yes, please post them (the bug may be there).

Comment: @user3094708 you didn't show the copy constructor. Maybe you don't have one but you delete sig2D in the destructor?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - `new` will throw if it fails. No need to check.

Comment: I have copy constructor template <class T> Signal<T>::Signal(Signal& s):N(s.N),M(s.M),sig2D(s.sig2D)
{}  .Is this OK? But I have still the same error.

Comment: @user3094708 no, this is not OK. You're creating a shallow copy. When you delete sig2D in one instance, the pointer in the other instance is invalidated too.

Comment: I change my copy constructor but still same error.              template <class T> Signal<T>::Signal(Signal& s):N(s.N),M(s.M){
 T** ss= new T*[s.N];
 for(int i=0;i<s.N;i++){
  ss[i]=new T[s.M];
 }
 for(int i=0;i<s.N;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<s.M;j++)
   ss[i][j]=s.sig2D[i][j];
}

Comment: @Henrkin I don't understand. Can you explain me what do you mean "When you delete sig2D in one instance, the pointer in the other instance is invalidated too"

Answer (score 0):

The most serious problem with your code is that you only return in the first if in zeroPadding which cause undefined returning value if the program flows into else.

```
if(s1.getWidth()>s2.getWidth() && s1.getHeight()==s2.getHeight()){

            im2.setWidth(s1.getWidth());
            im2.sig2D=new T*[im2.getWidth()];
            for(int i=0;i<im2.getWidth();i++){
                im2.sig2D[i]=new T[im2.getHeight()];
            }

            for (int i=s2.getWidth();i<s1.getWidth();i++)
                for(int j=0;j<s2.getHeight();j++){
                    im2.sig2D[i][j]=temp[j];
                }   
                return im2;  // <- return here

        }
          else if(s1.getHeight()<s2.getHeight() && s1.getWidth()>s2.getWidth()){
        // what will it return if the code comes to here
        setHeight(s2.getHeight());
        sig2D=new T*[getWidth()];
        for(int i=0;i<getWidth();i++){
            sig2D[i]=new T[getHeight()];
        }

        for (int i=0;i<s1.getWidth();i++)
            for(int j=s1.getHeight();j<s2.getHeight();j++){
                sig2D[i][j]=temp[j];
            }   
            (*this).zeroPadding(im2);
            }
       // or here
```

But there are also many problems with your code

First, properties and methods in the same object don't need `this`, just `sig2D[i][j]`, `zeroPadding(im2);`... is enough.

You're also generating lots of memory leaks by allocating memory without freeing. In the `addImage` function you create a new image

```
Image<T> *r=new Image(80,80);
```

then in the if you create a new image again without freeing the previous one

```
r=new Image(im2.getWidth(),im2.getHeight());
```

Besides, you're using allocated memory without checking for `NULL`

```
sig2D= new int*[N];
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    sig2D[i]=new int[M];
}

int *temp=new int[15];
for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
    temp[i]=0;
```

also in the addImage function, if it goes to the else

```
(*r)= zeroPadding(im2); // here breaks why?
```

if the new statement fails, the assignment also fails. And in the code you said it failed at the above line while in the comment you said it failed with `(*this)`:

> I when I called (*r)=(*r).zeroPadding(im2) instead of
>   (*r)=zeroPadding(im2) it passed so it's not problem with r, problem is
>   with (*this). I tought that (*this) is initialized in main(), am I
>   wrong?

Yes you're wrong. `this` is just a pointer to the current object, not a real variable, so if the object exists, access to `this` are always successful. But if `r` is not initialized then the line in your comment won't continue running.

Using `->` instead of `(*x).` will make your code shorter and cleaner

Last, please refix the indent of your code

Comment: In every place that I have =new I put it try and catch block (catch is like this catch(std::bad_alloc&){cout << "New failed";}  ) and debug from main. Function addImage go inside zeroPadding (*r)=zeroPadding(im2) and return to this line without error. But after come back to this line I put Step over and fail.

Comment: I agree with you that I don't need(*this).zeroPadding. I didn't put whole function zeroPadding because is big so I put only one part which are executed in this example in main. So my zeroPadding in this example start in else if where at the end of else if (*this).zeroPadding(im2) is called. After that first part od zeroPadding is executed (if part). So it's not necessary to have return in else if because at the end of else if I will call again zeroPadding which will execute part of function with return.I put try and catch in every place where I use new I didn't catch error.

Comment: you're assuming wrong. If it was called recursively again then the result will be consumed by the caller, which  `(*this).zeroPadding(im2);` was discarded by this line without returning to the outer caller. If you need tail recursion then use `return (*this).zeroPadding(im2);`

Comment: imagine `int a(int n) { if (somecondition) return n; else a(n - 1); }`, if control goes to else then nothing will be returned. Turn on all warning and see

Comment: @ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc you were rigth. I don't have error right now. Thank you.

Comment: I changed else part of addImage function so instead of (*r)= zeroPadding(im2);addImage(*r); I put return addImage(zeroPadding(im2)); so after this line if part of addImage is called. But It breaks in line (*r).sig2D[i][j]=(*this).sig2D[i][j]+(im2).sig2D[i][j]; when variable i become 3. I don't understand why it breaks when i=3 because in this example i goes from 0 to 4.