# class constructor with const reference

Tags: c++

in this class

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(){}
  Foo(Foo const &) {}
};
```

when would `Foo(Foo const &)` ever be called? I do not understand this kind of constructor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168201/what-is-a-copy-constructor-in-c

Comment: You'll probably find [**this page**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) informative.

Comment: This page also has a good general explanation of const, with your specific question in the section titled "Where it Gets Messy - in Parameter Passing"  : http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html

Comment: And while we're here, [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) Well, it just happens to be one of the, if not the, most important reasons for one of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called copy constructor. When you want to initialize a class instance by copying an existing instance, you'd probably want to use it.

const - you don't want to change the object you are copying.

reference - you don't want to copy the existing instance into the constructor, just to copy it again in the initialization.