# Chaining overloaded + operators

Tags: c++, class, object, math, overloading

I've been writing a polynomial class and I was overloading operators for it. I managed to (I think) successfully overload the += operator and now I created an external function that uses += for addition just like advised in many sources. It works but I can't chain them for some reason
When I try to add polynomials like this

```
poly a, b, c, d;
a=b+c+d;
```

I get an error: no matching function for call to 'poly::poly(const poly)'

My += function's main body isn't all that important but that's what it's like:

```
poly& operator+= (const poly& a){
        //implemented +=
        return *this;

    }
```

My addition function (outside of the class) looks like this:

```
const poly operator+ (poly a, const poly & b){
    a+= b;
    return a;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why is `operator+` returning a `const`?

Comment: Both `a` and `b` should be `const &`.

Comment: You are missing a [copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168201/what-is-a-copy-constructor-in-c).

Comment: Looks like you don't have a copy constructor for `poly`. `b + c` produces a `const poly` and your `operator +` takes a `poly` as first argument so it has to copy the `const poly` into the `poly a` but it can't, because there is no copy constructor `poly::poly(const poly &)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `poly` class is missing a copy constructor of the form `poly(const poly&)`. Note that if you already have a `poly(poly&)` that isn't enough. You need a copy constructor that takes a `const poly&` as a parameter.