# Is the default constructor not called when declaration and assignment are joined?

Tags: c++

I have created a class coor and overloaded a + operator

```
class coor
{
    coor(){std::cout<<"default constructor called\n";};
    coor operator +(coor param) const;
};

coor coor::operator+(coor param) const
{
    ....    
}


int main() {
    coor obj1;
    coor obj2;
    coor obj3 = obj1 + obj2;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the default constructor of obj3 is not called?
It is called when declarartion and assignment and seperated.

Comment: Here is the case when [the copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168201/what-is-a-copy-constructor-in-c) gets involved .

Comment: what is the content of operator+ method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
coor obj3 = obj1 + obj2
```

you *copy-construct* `obj3` from the result of `obj1 + obj2` (which is a so-called *r-value* and a temporary object).

Even though `=` is used here, it's not assignment but initialization.

Comment: Your answer implies that a copy-constructor will be called. But this not true with C++17 (`operator+` returns a prvalue, so no copy constructor is involved here).

Answer (score 1):

"Why is the default constructor of obj3 is not called?" - Because of the rules of [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) - which is what is happening here.